# Python неконстантные атрибуты класса

Tags: python, классы, атрибуты

```
class A:
    atr_1 = '1'
    atr_2 = atr_1 + '2'

my_dict = {'prefix.1': 1,
          'prefix.2': 2}

class B:
    atr_1 = 'prefix'
    atr_2 = [el.removeprefix(atr_1 + '.') for el in my_dict.keys()]
```

Вопрос по коду выше. В классе A успешно создаётся атрибут класса atr_1, а в классе B - нет, т.к. ошибка "`NameError: name 'atr_1' is not defined`", но почему в первом случае этой ошибки нет? И как делать подобные неконстантные атрибуты класса, которые общие для всех экземпляров? Или в Python это делается где-то в другом месте?

Comment: Интересно и так тоже не сработает: `atr_2 = [el.removeprefix(B.atr_1 + '.') for el in my_dict.keys()]` :)

Comment: в классе B тоже создается. Легко убедиться, добавив аналогичную строчку в B - atr_2 = atr_1 + '2'

Comment: @Эникейщик, но не для генератора списка :)

Comment: @gil9red так и вопрос не про генератор, а про класс :)

Comment: @gil9red у меня не сработал при обращении через имя класса.
предлагаю в __init__ это сделать

Comment: Ух какой там красивый айсберг скрывается под этим вопросом: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13913933/8324991

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Получилось через такой костыль:

```
class B:
    atr_1 = 'prefix'
    atr_2 = (lambda atr_1: [el.removeprefix(atr_1 + '.') for el in my_dict.keys()])(atr_1)

print(B.atr_2)
# ['1', '2']
```

Comment: о, или через лямбду. здорово :)

Comment: Хитро! Спасибо)

Comment: @Chudvan, пожалуйста :)